# figure* environment in twocolumn knitr/Sweave document

Tags: r, knitr, tex, sweave

Sounds like it should be a common problem, but I didn't find an obvious trick.
Consider the knitr Rnw file below,

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%\SweaveOpts{dev=pdf, fig.align=center}
\begin{figure*}
<<aaa, fig.width=8, fig.height=5, fig.show=hold>>=
plot(1,1)
@
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I would like this wide figure to span two columns, using a `{figure*}` LaTeX environment. Is there a hook for that?

EDIT: wrapping the chunk in `figure*` gives the following output.

[image]

Comment: You may have more luck at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MartinSchröder yes, agreed. But I should probably strip it down to the latex problem, and I'm not sure where the `kframe` environment came from in the first place (from the source, it looks like a private communication).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two facts:

1. `knitr` makes everything accessible for you, so LaTeX tricks are often unnecessary;
2. there is a [`chunk` hook](http://yihui.github.com/knitr/hooks) with which you can wrap your chunk results;

A simple-minded solutions is:

```
knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
                       sprintf('\\begin{figure*}\n%s\n\\end{figure*}', x)
})
```

I leave the rest of work to you to take care of more details in `options` (e.g. when `options$fig.keep == 'none'`, you should not wrap the output in `figure*`). You may want to see how [the default `chunk` hook](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks.R) for LaTeX is defined in `knitr` to know better how the `chunk` hook works.

However, in this case, I tend to write the LaTeX code by myself in the document instead of automatically creating it. After you have got `figure*`, you may start to think about `\caption{}` and `\label{}` ([not hard](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/81), but I still want to see them in LaTeX).

Comment: that sounds very promising, thanks. However, as I understand, this hook would apply to the each chunk in the document, right? If I want only one particular chunk to have this behavior, I should probably define a new optional hook, say fullwidth. Did I get this right?

Comment: Yes it applies to all chunks. For individual control, you may add a chunk option like `fullwidth`, then use `if (options$fullwidth) {use figure*...} else {normal output}` in the chunk hook, and the chunk looks like `<<..., fullwidth=TRUE>>=`

Comment: My first try was indeed to wrap the chunk in `\begin{figure*} \end{figure*}` but for some reason the alignment is broken (see edit).

Comment: I do not know. It sounds like a completely LaTeX problem now. Do some homework like why `\centering{}` does not work in `figure*` for you.

Comment: looking at the latex output, the whole chunk is in {kframe}, which alters the position. That's some pretty advanced TeX, apparently from the author of the framed LaTeX package. A TeX question indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about how knitr but for Sweave (and basic latex) there is in fact a trick: have the R code produce a pdf file, and then use standard `\includegraphics` to pull it in.

So with this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%\SweaveOpts{dev=pdf}

<<aaa,fig=FALSE,print=FALSE,echo=FALSE>>=
pdf("mychart.pdf", width=6, height=3)
set.seed(42)
plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)), type='l', main="yet another random walk")
invisible(dev.off())
@

\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics{mychart.pdf}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I got the document below (which I then converted from pdf to png):

[image]

Comment: C'mon, you're now in the Commonwealth. You left *elegance* way back home :)   There may be other tricks. It is always a good idea to check vignette that have Achim Zeileis as a (co-)author as he is a never-ending source of latex tricks.

Comment: admittedly I'm knitpicking, but I trust there exists some neater way. If I were to use this trick, I'd probably have `brew` reliably link the graphic filename between R and LaTeX.

Comment: I tend to have a subdirectory figures/ to which I write, and name the Sweave chunk the same as the resulting pdf. Works well.  Plus, you get caching for basically free b/c if the pdf exists, you may decide to skip recreating it.

Comment: My approach to reproducible research is to have the software take care of things that I cannot trust myself to do reliably. A consistent naming scheme is one of them. I respectfully recommend that you try `knitr`, it's proving to be mind changing vis-à-vis (cache|pgf|)Sweave old tricks.

Comment: It's in the queue, which is a polite way of saying that I have a metric ton of other things to get to first.  Also, nothing we have discussed here w.r.t. Sweave takes away from reproducible research approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem while preparing a figure that should span two columns in a IEEE two-column conference paper.

**Setting the chunk hook caused some strange error in my setup.**
Even this simple hook: `knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) x)`

But after looking into `knitr::opts_chunk$get()`, I realized that simply setting `fig.env="figure*"` solves the problem in an elegant way.

Here is how my chunk looks like in an Rnw file:

```
<<fig1, fig.width=18, fig.height=6, fig.env="figure*">>=
@
```

Comment: the question and @Yihui 's answer date back 2012, so things may well have changed